# Why use Controllers for Directives communication instead of Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm refactoring some of my Angular JS application, and I'm going to learn more about directives.

I've read many times that bind a controller to a directive is a good practice, if we want to share logic and get code clean.

Bind a `controller` to a `directive` to share common tasks between many directives is pretty simple and I understand the interest of this pattern. But my question is why do we need to use a controller ?

(Example code come from [this site](https://thinkster.io/egghead/directive-to-directive-communication/))

**Pattern 1 : Use controller to share logic between directives**

Bind a `controller` to `directive` :

```
app.directive("superhero", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",

    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.abilities = [];

      // [...] additional methods

      this.addFlight = function() {
        $scope.abilities.push("flight");
      };
    },

    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.addClass("button");
      element.bind("mouseenter", function () {
        console.log(scope.abilities);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Share logic with another directives :

```
app.directive("flight", function() {
  return {
    require: "superhero",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, superheroCtrl) {
      superheroCtrl.addFlight();
    }
  };
});
```

When I want to share logic between my controller I create a `Factory` that I inject into my controller. So why do not use the same pattern ?

**Pattern 2 : Use factory to share logic between directives**

Declare the new `factory` :

```
app.factory("myAwesomeFactory", function () {
    return {
        addFlight: function () { /* ... */ }
    };
});
```

Use the `factory` into `directive` :

```
app.directive("flight", function(myAwesomeFactory) {
    return {
        require: "superhero",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            myAwesomeFactory.addFlight();
        }
    };
});
```

I can't understand why the first method is better than the second.

**Bonus question :** Why do we use `this` keyword in controllers which are binded to directives ?

Thanks a lot. I've found lots of tutorials about how to bind a controller to directive. But no one explains why we need to do this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest reason I've run across is that, since services are singletons, you can run into serious problems by having multiple directives relying on logic from the same service. This is why anything that has to do with the view is done through the controller. While you can sometimes get away with using the service within the directive, it's better to avoid the practice altogether if possible.